# How to import styles into an iframe with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, create-react-app

I'm using CRA (create-react-app) to create a website. In this website, I use React.createPortal to inject a component into an iframe, like so:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(
  <SomeComponent />,
  this.iframeRef.current.contentDocument.body
);
```

But the styles are obviously not passed down into the iframe. Like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/kk05rl6kpv.

Any ideas on how to move a stylesheet chunk into the iframe?

Comment: the problem is , if you inspect the page you will create another document inside your page, with <html><head><body> ... and you lost the reference to your css.... I know is not a solution but if you change      <div className="Red">HI! I should red!</div>, in :     <div style={{color:'red'}}>HI! I should red!</div>,   it work.... I know is not a answer at your question but i hope a good way to find solution

Comment: @MatteoAngelotti This is actually an answer. Consider posting it. CSS in JS is pretty much idiomatic to React.

Comment: @MatteoAngelotti I actually thought of that before. And I also thought of using CRA styled components with webpack loader: `import "styled-components/macro";` (see: https://medium.com/styled-components/css-prop-support-for-create-react-app-37e8c5d96861). The problem with the `style` prop is that it doesn't add prefixes, so it renders it useless for heavy stuff. And the problem with the loader is that, although it does add prefixes (super cool), it will inject it as a stylesheet and not as inline styles :/, so I'm back to square one.

Comment: Maybe, if using code-splitting and somehow find a way to know which <style> element was injected? I did something similar, where I added `.chunk-buster{content:"unique-file-name.scss"}` at the top of the stylesheets and then had to search through the stylesheets inner text to find this class after `() => import("../styles/unique-file-name.scss")`. Worked, but I do not like it as it requires the developer to add the class and still has to be processed in user-land.